# How to run R projects / use their relative paths from the terminal without setwd() resp. cd

Tags: r, cmd, rstudio, workflow, project

I'm kinda lost on that one:

I have set up an R project, let's call it "Test Project.Rproj". The beauty of R projects is the possibility to use relative paths (relative to the .Rproj file). My project consists of a "main.R" script, which is saved on the same level as the .Rproj file.
Additionally I have a directory called 'Output', where I want my plots and exported data to be saved. My "main.R" file looks like the following:

```
my_df <- data.frame(A = 1:10, B = 11:20)
my_df |>
  writexl::write_xlsx(here::here("Output", 
                                 paste0("my_df_", 
                                        stringr::str_replace_all(as.character(Sys.time()), ":", ""), 
                                        ".xlsx")))
```

My final goal is to automate the execution of the 'main.R' file using the Windows Task Scheduler. But in order to do so, I have to be able to run the script from the terminal. The problem here is the working directory. When opening an R project, all the paths are relative to .Rproj file. But in the terminal the current working directory is `<C:\Users\my_name>`. Of course I could manually set the working directory via `cd "path\to\my\project`. But I would like to avoid that.

My current call for the execution of the main.R file in the terminal is the following:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.0\bin\Rscript" -e "source('C:/Users/my_name/path/to/my/project/main.R')"
```

My two ideas for a solution are the following, but I am happy for other suggestions as well.

1. In order to replicate the usual use of a project: Is there a way to execute the .Rproj
   file from the terminal? In order to create a similar environment as in RStudio, where all the relative paths are working, when executing scripts from the project afterwards?
2. There are two packages adressing the problem of relative paths: `rprojroot` and `here`,  where the former is the basis for the latter. I am pretty sure that `here` does not provide the needed functionality. I tried adding `here::i_am("main.R)` to my main.R file, but the project root directory still is not found when executing in the terminal from a working directory outside the project.
   For `rprojroot` to work, I think it is also necessary to have your current working directory somewhere within the project. But this package offers a lot of functionality, so I am not sure wheter I am overlooking something.

So I would be happy about any help. Maybe it is impossible and I have to change the working directory manually - then I would be glad to know that as well.

Some links I used in my research:

https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2017/12/workflow-vs-script/

https://malco.io/2018/11/05/why-should-i-use-the-here-package-when-i-m-already-using-projects/

http://jenrichmond.rbind.io/post/how-to-use-the-here-package/

Thanks a lot!

Edit: My current implementation is an additional R script, where I manually set the working directory via setwd() and source the main.R file. However it is always suggested to avoid setwd, which is why this whole question exists.

Comment: Hi there - did you find a solution for this? I would like to use the here package in a similar context and am foreseeing the same issues.